# Raise an event from within a task

Tags: c#, events

I have a manager class which spawns a task to complete a long running operation.
I would like to be able to invoke a method on the manager class to notify listeners via an event of status, errors etc.

When using a non-task approach this is easy.

How do I invoke a method, or raise an event on  the manager class from within the task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a way for anyone holding an instance of the `Task` to be able to listen to these events? Because you can just raise events from tasks normally, and have anyone listening to them be notified.

Comment: The `IProgress<T>` interface and `Progress<T>` implementation already do what you ask and even raise an event for each notification

Answer (score 0):

I would define the interface that you need to communicate this to the manager class and then pass this into the task via a method parameter.

For error notifications throwing an exception will suffice as long as the exception is observed on the task via `await`, `Task.Wait()`, `Task.Result` or `Task.Exception`

If the notification is for progress there is already an `[IProgress<T>][1]` interface you can use.

But for any custom notification to the manager class I'd add an appropriate interface and implement it in the manager class.